# Making radcombobox work like html select (in terms of attribute, events)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Pardon me, as I don't have sample code to paste here.

The page has `asp:DropdownList` which has the events such as `change`. The eventhandler is attached using jquery (on the lines of `$('#mydropdown').bind('change', function() {});` which in turn makes an ajax call (think of 3 dropdowns where dropdown 3 is dependent on dropdown 2 and dropdown 2 is dependent on dropdown 1).

A change request needs me to use Telerik RadComboBox which doesn't have identical model (such as `change` event, `options` attribute etc). I would prefer not to modify the existing code that gets triggered on the `change` event, which does state management & ajax calls on the client side.

Can someone help me redirect the RadComboBox events (`OnSelectedIndexChanged` to the dropdown events (`change`), thereby making sure that the code doesn't have to care if its RadComboBox or a html select- because it is able to receive the notification of `change` event).

Post comments, if this isn't clear.

Comment: There is no easy way around telerik controls. Cant you just make your existing function take parameters and call it from both change events?

Comment: @BiffMaGriff: The code that handles the event is a generic one. i.e. a kind of 1 page js file that handles related dropdowns, refreshing it, maintaining state, resetting it, clearing it etc. Unless someone has come across this kind of scenario, I will have to write this code. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Please explain the reason when down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this.Telerik controls behave in different way.The events of this functions are also different.

The javascript used and the method of telerik are different.

Changing the RadcomboBox `OnSelectedIndexChanged`to `change` , the logic would be same except just finding controls

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything new that isn't stated in the question. No, the logic isn't same except finding controls. For e.g. you can do `$(#myhtmldropdown).val()`, which you can't do with telerik radcombobox, to give you an example.

Comment: see the second line The javascript used and the method of telerik are different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the `RenderMode` property on the control? This allows you to define the mode that it should render to the page in. Classic is the default method that Telerik use for creating the controls, but They have Lightweight and Native modes. At least one of them renders a typical `select` onto the page.

[Demo Page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/rendermode/defaultcs.aspx)

A word of warning, your existing code *might* work against these objects, but it could equally introduce a number of bugs - thorough testing is recommended.

Comment: It seems the requirement is to have it show it ajax (non-native). I didn't know such a property existed. Thanks for the answer.